# pymysql returns wrong values for BIT type

Tags: python, mysql, type-conversion, pymysql

I'm using `pymysql==0.10.1` (python3.7) to read a table with a BIT column, and getting wrong values:

```sql
CREATE TABLE root.numeric
(BIT_COL       BIT(10));
insert into root.numeric
values (b'0010001000');
insert into root.numeric
values (b'0000100000');
```

and then

```py
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                sql = f"select * from `root`.`numeric`;"
                cursor.execute(sql)
                result = cursor.fetchone()
                print("mysql payload", result)
```

getting:

```
mysql payload {'BIT_COL': b'\x00\x88'} # nice
mysql payload {'BIT_COL': b'\x00 '}.   # not nice
```

why is that? I checked and it looks like the pymysql code isn't converting anything for BIT fields.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the [code](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/converters.py) "MySQLdb doesn't process bits, so we shouldn't either", so the proper conversion is:

```py
    def convert_bit(self, b):
        """ bit fields are packed as big-endian unsigned long long,
            we translate them to human-readable int/long"""
        b = b"\x00" * (8 - len(b)) + b # pad w/ zeroes
        return struct.unpack(">Q", b)[0]
```